# How to call webservice from ember

Tags: javascript, web-services, ember.js

How can i produce web service call from ember. now I'm using simple web api which returns json data, but need to connect web service, which is working with xml file

Comment: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/best-practices-for-web-service-design-with-ember-data/5654

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/customizing-adapters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont plan on using Ember Data you can just convert the XML to a JS object in the `Route`s model hook, like this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return $.get('/url-to-some-xml').then(function(xml){
      //here is where you would convert your xml to a JS object
      return parsedXml
    })
  }
});
```

your template would then have access to the data in the `parsedXml` object.

If you are using Ember Data then you would convert the XML to a JS object in a Serializers [`normalizePayload`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizePayload) hook.
see [Ember Data serialize on fetch and deserialize on POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203749/ember-data-serialize-on-fetch-and-deserialize-on-post/25204361#25204361) for details on how to use the `normalizePayload` hook.