# Ember Data serialize on fetch and deserialize on POST

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember data to get data from a remote server.
My model definition is as follows -

```
App.Publisher = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    appName: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    appType: DS.attr('number'),
    streamType: DS.attr('number'),
    sslEnabled: DS.attr('number'),
    protocol: DS.attr('number'),

});
```

And the response from the server is in the following format -

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "aurus",
  url: "1111",
  app_name: "superprofs",
  app_type: 1,
  stream_type: 1,
  ssl_enabled: 1,
  protocol: 1,
  created_at: "2014-08-08T10:52:40.000Z",
  updated_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
},
```

But since the key from `server` is in `underscore` format and my `model` keys are `camelCase`, 
the values from the server are not being set.

How can I make my model keys to adapt to the format of data the server is sending(`underscore`) and then when I call save/create/update in ember js, I want the data to be sent in `underscore` format, since my server API is expecting the data in the underscore format

Answer (score 1):

For the folks who are running into the same problem, I fixed it using `ActiveModelAdapter`

I made my ApplicationAdpater to extend from DS.ActiveModelAdapter.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create `App.PublisherSerializer` which depending on which adapter you are using should extend from either the `DS.RESTSerializer`, `DS.ActiveModelSerializer` or `DS.JSONSerializer`.

You would need to overwrite the [serialize](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serialize) and [normalizePayload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizePayload) hooks to do what you need.

keep in mind that ember data needs to have a root key with of the record type, in the normalizePayload hook you should end up returning an object looking like

```
{
    publishers: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "aurus",
        url: "1111",
        appName: "superprofs",
        appType: 1,
        streamType: 1,
        sslEnabled: 1,
        protocol: 1,
        createdAt: "2014-08-08T10:52:40.000Z",
        updatedAt: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }]
}
```

here is a bin showing how to use the `normalizePayload` hook: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mucici/1/edit

Comment: I am not able to get my head around this, pls could you tell me where do I write this code ?

Comment: are you trying to load an array of data or just a single record?

Comment: array of data, how does it matter but ?

Comment: it doesnt really: i added a working bin to the answer

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. But I found a neat solution by using ActiveModelAdapter. I will update my answer.